# Shuffle assigned array when a new element is added to array

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary, data-structures

## Use case:

There are various users who put their ideas in an idea pool. The users keep on coming in the pool. There is a start time and an end time to put ideas in the pool. Now after putting ideas in the pool, they are assigned 3 ideas each to review. Similarly, other users get random ideas to review from pool. It's mandatory to review 3 reviews. You get to see feedback on your ideas. It's important to have feedback to move forward. So users should not wait to review other people, neither should they wait (much) to get feedback on their ideas.

#### Examples:

**User 1** enters review (or idea) pool, then **User 2** enters review pool, similarly **User 3** and **User 4**. As soon as **User 4** enters review pool, the ideas are shuffled and they get to review each other ideas.

```
{ 1: [2,3,4], 2: [1,3,4], 3: [1,2,4], 4: [1,2,3] }
```

Here as you can see, **User 1**, **2** & **3** have to wait till the group count reaches to 4.

Now **User 5** enters review pool, and waits for **User 6**, **7**, & **8**

Or

**User 5** enters review pool, and **User 5** is assigned with ideas of **User 2**, **3** & **4**. Then **User 6** enters and it is assigned with ideas of **User 3**, **4** & **5** to review. This is fine, but then **User 2**, **3** & **4** ideas are being reviewed more than 3 times (affordable)

But what is not affordable, is that in the last, **User *N*** reviews **User *N-1***, ***N-2*** & ***N-3*** ideas, but no one reviews **User *N*** ideas because he is the last person. Also **User *N-1*** ideas are being reviewed by only **User *N*** and **User *N-2*** ideas are being reviewed by only **User *N-1*** and **User *N***

```
{ N-2: [N-5, N-4, N-3], N-1: [N-4, N-3, N-2], N: [N-3, N-2, N-2] }
```

One solution is to shuffle the last 4 and add ideas to reviews.

#### Example:

```
{ N-2: [N-5, N-4, N-3, N-1, N], N-1: [N-4, N-3, N-2, N], N: [N-3, N-2, N-2] }
```

I don't find it a viable solution. If you understand the use case, it would be great if we could brainstorm and get to a solution.

Thanks.

PS. *If you can help me frame the title of the question better, that would be great.*

Comment: as stated as is, your problem as infinite solution since you didn't define an objective function (a cost to minimize). To avoid someone's idea not being reviewed at least twice, you may consider user N who enters and review user N-1's and N-2's idea, and keep a review for upcoming user N+1. This way user N+1 is ensured to be reviewed once as soon as he enters (and will be reviewed twice when N+2 enters). If you want the guy to be reviewed twice as soon as he enters, keep two review open (idem only review N-1's idea)

Comment: A good starting point could be to build the classes with their relations (eg. Idea, User, Pool).

Comment: Do you know, before you start, how many users will be entering ideas, and how many total ideas will be entered?

Comment: Missing an idea of the time. Obviously all ideas don't come at once, but If how long can you wait for more than three ideas before having to review some? a bit of defined flexibility there would allow some solution...